# Deleting edges in a graph stored as adjacency list

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement an algorithm for finding an Eulerian path in undirected graph stored as adjacency list. I need a fast way(linear time) to remove an edge from the graph.

My initial idea was to use something like

`vector<list<pair<Vertex, List<Vertex>::iterator>>> Graph`

so when I delete the edge in one direction I will have a fast way to delete it in the oposite direction using the iterator to the place where it is stored for the reverse direction. However several sources claim that those iterators won't be valid anymore, because as I start deleting items the pointer structure will become different and those iterators won't point to the right elements anymore.

My question is, is there a way to achieve deleting an edge in O(1) time using adjacency lists or is there a way to mark the edge somehow, so when I am in the adjacent vertex I will know for sure that the edge in the oposite direction was traversed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if there is no algorithm that can satisfy your requirement? Also, you mention one approach, have you tried it?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the algorithm I studied claims to work in O(|E|) time, but doesn't specify how to delete the edges efficiently. I am new to c++ and have no idea how the list data structure is implemented. If it is doubly-linked I feel like my approach should work as the node can update the pointers of adjacent nodes before being deleted, but several posts claim it doesn't, so maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

> I need a fast way(linear time) to remove an edge from the graph.

It's possible, but you have to change your graph representation, because of problems you have described.

**Approach 1** -- guaranteed O(logE) complexity

Just use `std::set` instead of `std::list`:

`std::vector<std::set<int>> Graph;`

This allows to traverse & process all adjacent nodes in the same manner:

```
// adj is your graph,
// v is current vertex
for (auto &w : adj[v]) {
  // process edge [v, w]
}
```

But you can [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/) opposite edge in O(logE):

```
// remove [v,w] and [w,v]
adj[v].erase(w);
adj[w].erase(v);
```

**Approach 2** -- average O(1), worst case O(E)

Constant time complexity is possible with std::unordered_set, but only on average:

`std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> Graph;`

Traversing and erasing patterns stay the same, but personally I would prefer approach 1.